# Call to undefined function imagecreatefromwebp inside wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a wordpress plugin that downloads images. I've seen this problems that sometimes a file taken from web, despite having a jpg extension, is actually in webp format. So i made a simple test feature to see if an image is in webp format:

```
 if ($im = @imagecreatefromwebp($filename)) {
    imagejpeg($im, $filename.'.jpeg', 100);
 }
```

I've tested in a test file put on the same server where wordpress is, just to see if the conversion is made and indeed it works.

Then i've put the same code inside the wordpress plugin but i get:

```
 Call to undefined function imagecreatefromwebp()
```

How is it possible? The server is the same, the plugin it's just one folder away from the test file. The test file outside wordpress works, inside worpress the function doesn't exists. Is wordpress disabling some of basic php functions?

Comment: Is the `gd`-extension loaded/active in the php.ini/php-setup for the webserver/fpm part of the php setup?

Comment: For sure it is. On the standlone file it works!

Comment: The same problem here. Have you found  a solution?

Comment: Not a direct one. I've made a standalone `ConvertWebp.php` and then made an ajax call to this external file. Awful solution, but it works.

Comment: Please share more details - are you absolutely sure that both files use the same php.ini?

Comment: Absolutely sure, they are on the same server, on the same folder, there is only one php version and obviously just one php.ini

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reasons why it is not working. But the most common is that gd extension is not enabled.

Open **php.ini** file and uncomment the line that says `;extension=gd` by removing that semi-colon (;).

So change `;extension=gd` to `extension=gd`

Comment: I'm sorry, i thought i've explained it clearly. Extension is enabled on php.ini because on the standalone file it works. It's only inside wordpress that doesn't work

Comment: Looks like the `gd2` extension was renamed to `gd` from PHP 7.4 to 8.1.